# Is there Amazon client that allows make calls to API Gateway without manually create headers like: X-Amz-Date,Authorization?

Tags: java, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Is there Amazon client for java that allows make calls to API Gateway without manually create headers like: X-Amz-Date,Authorization ?

I am looking for something like: apigatewayClient.sendRequest("https://my_gateway_api service")

Comment: I thing **The response shows that the API Gateway custom authorizer returns a 403 Forbidden** or **The response shows that API Gateway returns a 401 Unauthorized**

Comment: FWIU, are you looking for something like this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-console, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-apigateway-generated-java-sdk.html ?